# Compile program for older versions of Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, compilation

I have an objective c script that takes a Mac's system information and outputs it as an XML with specific tags. It works on Mountain Lion and Lion, but doesn't work with any versions besides those. Up to 10.5 would be ideal. When I run it on 10.6.8, I get a Bad CPU error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you set the "OS X Deployment Target" to 10.5 in the Info tab of the Project settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 4.5.1 comes with OS X 10.7 and 10.8 SDKs. To compile programs that run on earlier OS X versions, you have to set the "OS X Deployment Target" in the Info tab of the program settings.

"Automatic Reference Counting" is only supported on OS X 10.6 and later (see [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html)). If you want to deploy to 10.5, you have to compile without ARC. So either

- you create a new project and uncheck the "Use Automatic Reference Counting", or
- you set "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting" to "No" in the Build Settings.

To build executables that run on 32-bit processors, you have to set "Architectures" to "32-bit Intel" in the Build settings. By default, Xcode 4.5.1 will compile for the architecture of the compile machine (which most probably is 64-bit). But in this case you can not use ARC, because ARC requires the so-called "modern runtime", which is available only on 64-bit systems.

Comment: I tried not to disable ARC and remain at 10.6. I changed OS X Deployment Target and still got the Bad CPU type in executable

Comment: @Ali: Can you execute "file <executable>" on the command line - both on the machine where you compile it, and on the 10.6 machine. This might help to find the problem.

Comment: The mac I compile on is 64 bit and the 10.6 one is 32 bit. You think that could be the problem? If so, how would I fix that?

Comment: @Ali: Yes. I will add some information to my answer. Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: I received a Clang LLvM 1.0 Error. Could that have something to do with ARC? Even though I'm compiling under OSX Deployment Target 10.6?

Comment: error: -fobjc-arc is not supported with fragile abi
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: @Ali: OK, I see the problem now. If you look at the "Objective-C Feature Availability Index" (link in my answer) then you see that ARC on OS X requires the so-called "modern runtime", which is available only on 64-bit systems. - This means that there is no way to compile a program with ARC for a 32-bit computer.

Comment: Is the only option then to change my code for Macs not capable of ARC?

Comment: @Ali: Yes, ARC is only available on 64-bit computers. If you want to support 32-bit computers then you can not use ARC.